# How to group sql range query by clause

Tags: postgresql, navicat

I am receiving a error while building the index. I recently switched to PostgreSQL and I am using Navicat. The error is coming from the Locations table that has the zip code, city, state, latitude and longitude.

[image]

```
indexing index 'location_core'...
collected 84068 docs, 0.7 MB
sorted 0.1 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 84068 docs, 716268 bytes
total 0.686 sec, 1043676 bytes/sec, 122495.78 docs/sec
indexing index 'user_core'...
ERROR: index 'user_core': sql_range_query: ERROR:  column "locations.latitude" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...sers"."updated_at")::int AS "updated_at", RADIANS(locations....
                                                             ^
 (DSN=pgsql://lexi87:***@localhost:5432/dating_development).
total 0 docs, 0 bytes
total 0.007 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 0.00 docs/sec
indexing index 'user_delta'...
ERROR: index 'user_delta': sql_range_query: ERROR:  column "locations.latitude" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...sers"."updated_at")::int AS "updated_at", RADIANS(locations....
```

How exactly can I put them in a group by clause? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which is exactly the operation that caused the error? What you were doing? The error is typical of an illegal SQL query. Maybe the query is generated from Navicat, and there is a problem with the software.

Comment: I am rebuilding thinking sphinx, so that's when the error appeared. I edited the post.